# amazon s3 path in opencart for images in config php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, opencart, config

I am using s3 fr storing images for store in amazon web services.so i m giving the path of the s3 bucket in `admin/config.php` file for `directory_image`.
The path i m giving is
http://domain.s3.amazonaws.com (bucket url).

but when i m giving this path in config php file for image directory.It doesn't work. Please let me know if anything else also needs to be done to make the s3 path work in opencart.

Is there any extension needs to be installed to make s3 image bucket path work in opencart framework.

Answer (score 0):

after path changed in config, you should change in tool/image.php file, code start with /image it should be replace with your s3 domain name..it will work definitely.

Comment: have you used s3 in opencart?